# PostgreSQL delete a nested key of json column

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am using postgres DB in my application. Consider below is my json object in postgres table

```
{
"key1":"abc",
"key2":{
  "key3":"xyz"
}
}
```

If i execute the below query

```
 UPDATE table SET data = (data - 'key1');
```

key1 got deleted and updated in DB. But i need to delete key3(which is inside key2), i couldn't find any exact query to delete that. Kindly post your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`#-` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

> deletes the field or array element at the specified path, where path elements can be either field keys or array indexes.

```
update the_table
   set data = data #- '{key2, key3}'
```

Comment: So it will delet only key3 from key2 right?

Comment: Why not see for yourself: `select '{"key1":"abc","key2":{"key3":"xyz"}}'::jsonb #- '{key2, key3}'`